# Playing video in MPMoviePlayerController in fullscreen issue

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

I'm playing a video in my app from youtube via LBYouTubeView kit. I have used two way of playing the video one by pressing the button and the other once the app starts. When I press the the button it runs in full screen but, when the app starts it doesn't play in full screen while I am using the same code.

How can I solve this problem please?

Thanks from now.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.controller = [[LBYouTubePlayerController alloc] initWithYouTubeURL:URL quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
    self.controller.delegate = self;
    self.controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    self.controller.view.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.controller.view];

    [self.controller setFullscreen:YES];
}

-(IBAction)play{
 //The same code above
}
```

Comment: Try in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: What does `LBYouTubePlayerController` have to do with `MPMoviePlayerController`? I dont know the former and sure enough find your tagging confusing.

Comment: The LBYouTubePlayerController run the MPMoviePlayerController in full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just done a sample application using the above mentioned code. You are correct, I didn't get the fullscreen when I added the code in viewDidLoad.

I changed your code to `viewDidAppear` method instead of `viewDidLoad` and it worked perfectly.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   self.controller = [[LBYouTubePlayerController alloc] initWithYouTubeURL:URL quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
   self.controller.delegate = self;
   self.controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
   self.controller.view.center = self.view.center;
   [self.view addSubview:self.controller.view];
   [self.controller setFullscreen:YES];
}
```

I think when you call it in the `viewDidLoad` the view is being loaded, not fully loaded I think that causes the issue.

Comment: Thanks it works. I have tried it with `viewDidAppear` and it didn't work now with `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` it works well. What is the difference?

Comment: `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` is a delegate method, which'll automatically called when the view is appeared. If you write just like `viewDidAppear` it'll be a custom method. Then you need to call it manually